# SonarQube: how to use bash script variable inside yaml file

Tags: bash, yaml, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I want to create conditional pr_number variable and after assign it to the Dsonar.pullrequest.key. This is how I am trying to do it, but it's not working: pr_number remaining undefined

```
 name: SonarQube

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  sonarqube:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run sonarqube
        run:
          if [[ -z "${{github.event.number}}" ]]; then pr_number=${{ github.event.release }}; else pr_number=${{ github.event.number }}; fi |
          sonar-scanner
            -Dsonar.pullrequest.key=$pr_number
```

Comment: You said "it's not working" but can you be more specific? (namely, adding an error log or so would be useful to get a so-called [mre])

Answer (score 0):

As a solution i added command arguments using inline if statement conditional and immediately concat it ,inside sonarqube.yml using bash script when github.event.number and pullrequest.base is null

```
- name: Run sonarqube
        run:
          sonar-scanner
          -Dsonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=dependency-check-report.html
          "-Dsonar.pullrequest.key=`if [ -z "${{github.event.number}}"  ]; then echo ${{github.sha}}; else echo ${{github.event.number}}; fi`"
          "-Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=`if [ -z "${{github.head_ref}}"  ]; then echo ${{github.sha}}; else echo ${{github.head_ref}}; fi`"
          -Dsonar.pullrequest.base=${GITHUB_BASE_REF#refs/heads/}
          -Dsonar.pullrequest.github.repository=${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}
          -Dsonar.pullrequest.github.endpoint=${GITHUB_API_URL}
```